# Issue in secure file upload script using command line AV

Tags: php, file, file-upload, xampp, antivirus

I have a secure file upload function that's part of my website 
and I'm using an antivirus to help me checking the file a user trying to upload.

This is my uploadprocess.php file

```
$target_tmp = "D:\avscan\u\\"; 
$file = basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']) ;
if($file != "")
$_SESSION['file'] = $file;


$target = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ssd\Uploads\\'; 

$file_path = $target_tmp.$file;

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) 
{

    $safe_path = escapeshellarg($file_path);

    $command = 'scancl'. $safe_path. ' --stdout';
    $out = '';
    $int = -1;

    $output = exec($command, $out, $int); 
            echo "The output is" .$output;
     echo $int;        
     exit(0);

    //Checking for Virus. 
    if ($int == 0) {

        $target = $target.$file; 
        //echo $target; exit(0);
        copy($file_path, $target); 
        $uploaded = "The file ". $_SESSION['file']. "has been uploaded";
        $clean = 'File is Clean.';
        $_SESSION['status'] = $clean;
        $_SESSION['upload'] = $uploaded;
        header("location: ../upload.php");
        exit(0);
    }
    // File is a virus.
    else {
        $mal = 'Contains Malware';
        $deny_up = "Unable to Upload Your File!";
        $_SESSION['status'] = $mal;
        $_SESSION['upload'] = $deny_up;
        header("location: ../upload.php");
        exit(0);
    }


}
else 
{
    echo "SORRY, There was a Problem Uploading Your File."; exit(0);
    $err_upload = "SORRY, There was a Problem Uploading Your File.";
    $_SESSION['err'] = err_upload;
    header("location: ../upload.php");
    exit(0);
}
```

It prints me value of 1 for the $int for all files (malicious and non ones) This is my second try with a different AV now I'm using Avira and before I was using clamscan

can someone share me some hints, and tell me what's going on

PS the system is installed on XAMPP if that makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific about what's not working here? In theory what you doing seems fine at least for ClamAV since it has these return codes (from man clamscan):

```
RETURN CODES
       0 : No virus found.

       1 : Virus(es) found.

       2 : Some error(s) occured.
```

Maybe it want to log the output of the exec call, if you are not getting the exit code you expect the reason should be in the output (like missing a command line flag).